# RazorSQL and sqldevelopper not enable to connect to oracle DB on Mac with docker

Tags: docker, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, razorsql

**This is my terminal**

> nathanjobs@Air-de-Nathan ~ % docker exec -it competent_dirac sqlplus
system/oracle@//localhost:1521/xe

> SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Feb 3 01:13:23 2021

> Version 19.3.0.0.0

>Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

>  ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service

> requested in connect descriptor

> Enter user-name: 
system 
Enter password:  
Last Successful login time:
Wed Feb 03 2021 01:10:26 +00:00

> Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release

> 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.3.0.0.0

> SQL> show user

> USER is "SYSTEM" SQL>

I can make a connection to oracle with login: system and password: oracle but when I use razor or sqldeveloper I have this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW5S7.png)

the same problem in Razor I need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your terminal tap 'docker-compose up -d' load the docker image and in the docker folder add this file

 version: '2.1'

  services:

    oracle:

      image: quay.io/maksymbilenko/oracle-12c

       container_name: oracle

      restart: unless-stopped

       ports:

         - 8089:8080

         - 1521:1521

       volumes:

         - $PWD/oracle:/u01/app/oracle

       environment:

        - DBCA_TOTAL_MEMORY=2048'

save as docker-compose.yml